# Couldn't accept own response to question on StackOverflow

Tags: bug, status-norepro, accepted-answer, self-answer

So, a well-respected user over on Stack Overflow thinks I may have encountered a bug on my recent post, and requested i post over here mentioning it:

[FragmentPagerAdapter troubles and woes: Constructor Undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9799193/fragmentpageradapter-troubles-and-woes-constructor-undefined)

I asked a question and eventually (within a couple of hours) sorted out the problem and posted my own response, explaining what I did to solve the problem. So after posting my response, I tried to check off the response I made as the solution. SO gave me an orange box saying I had to wait six hours before doing that, so I did. I tried again before heading to bed, still no luck. I tried again the next day, well over 8 hours, and still couldn't do it. So I flagged my response, saying that I still couldn't mark the post as the solution.

I got a response today (as a 'helpful flag') from someone:

> "Can you please ask about this on Meta Stack Overflow? It might be a
>   bug. – [Will](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1228/will)♦ 1 hour ago"

And here was the flag I sent that was deemed helpful:

> I cannot flag this comment as the solution. It's exactly what I did to
>   solve the problem, and no matter when I've tried to check it off as
>   the solution, it always says I can do so in six hours: which has long
>   since gone by since I posted the solution. – 19 hours ago   helpful

Comment: Looks accepted to me... You would have had to wait 48 hours, which should have elapsed about 12 hours ago. But if it was telling you six hours after that - or immediately after posting your answer - then that's a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you were finally able to mark it accepted:

[image]

Comment: Yep, after Will responded to my comment, I went ahead and tried again and it worked fine. Either way, it seemed odd that it took not eight hours, but more like a day (don't know the exact time table to be honest). I'm fine with it taking awhile, and I wouldn't be surprised if it's more due to my still-low reputation more than anything else. But if someone with 50k rep thought it should be posted here on meta, I post it here on meta! So long as I got the response in so other users can see a complete solution, that's all that matters!