# Quorum badge does not update on Stack Overflow when requirements are met

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

This is my second post on meta, and I think I may have a second bug to report? The badge, Quorum: One post with score of 2 on meta over @ StackOverflow has not appeared on my profile, even though I submitted [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126700/couldnt-accept-own-response-to-question-on-stackoverflow) last week, and received six votes. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You now have the badge.

As part of that association overhaul, we stopped syncing GUIDs between accounts because it was borderline insanity with this many sites (APIv1 still fakes them based on a lookup map taken at the time of the switch-over).  They always skewed and it was more trouble than it was worth, especially since you have an `AccountId` (project Costanza Wallet) that *is* properly synced and maintained at a network level.

Some old badges were based on GUID and stopped working with new users who got a random GUID that no longer synced up, specifically: **Precognitive**, **Quorum** and **Convention**.  They have just been converted to use AccountIds and should now be reliable (due to GUID skew, they weren't 100%).

Comment: Cool! Glad we're steadily streamlining our systems!

Comment: How long should it take for this badge to take effect? For I am in a similar situation to the OP, just not as long a time frame

Comment: @thecoshman - badges that are cross-site (all non-SQL badges really, but in practice it's chat/meta badges) run once an hour...I see that you've gotten it since this was posted :)