# Quorum badge does not show up in "Choose which badge to track"

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, badges

I've just realised that the Quorum badge does not show up in "Choose which badge to track",

[image: Choose which badge to track]

in any of the three cases:

- You have made no progress at all;
- You have a Meta quetion with one vote (50% progress)
- You have been awarded it.

[image: No quorum]

Is there any design reason for this?

---

Note that this question seems to me to be different from [Quorum badge does not update on Stack Overflow when requirements are met](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127515/quorum-badge-does-not-update-on-stack-overflow-when-requirements-are-met).